# Remove shadow in 3D plots with different viewpoint

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

Consider the following two plots

```
plot1=Plot3D[Exp[x + y], {x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All, 
ViewPoint -> {-2.883444524117677`, -0.3079985688886338`, 
 1.7438132233408123`}]
```

[image]

```
plot2=Plot3D[Exp[x + y], {x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All, 
ViewPoint -> {0.12653180240704998`, -3.0663067393188728`, 
1.4253956234629264`}]
```

[image]

I want plot2 to have the same lighting as in plot1. I do not want to see any shadow in the peak area as seen in plot2. So how to remove this shadow effect coming from a different viewpoint.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use "Ambient" lighting option:

```
plot1 = Plot3D[Exp[x + y], {x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All, 
  Lighting -> {"Ambient", White}, 
  ViewPoint -> {-2.883444524117677`, -0.3079985688886338`, 
    1.7438132233408123`}]
```